Error: to Calculate shifted delta code error for one image
I am trying to find Shifted delta and running code for one image. and Im getting error on the highligted line. I have Also attached the screen shot of the error.
import numpy as np
import cv2
from scipy.fftpack import dct, idct

def compute_cepstrum(image):
    # Compute the 2D DCT (Discrete Cosine Transform)
    dct_image = dct(dct(image.T, norm='ortho').T, norm='ortho')
    # Compute the log magnitude
    log_magnitude = np.log(np.abs(dct_image) + 1e-8)
    # Compute the inverse DCT to get the cepstrum
    cepstrum = idct(idct(log_magnitude.T, norm='ortho').T, norm='ortho')
    return cepstrum

def compute_delta_cepstrum(cepstrum, delta=1):
    rows, cols = cepstrum.shape
    delta_cepstrum = np.zeros((rows, cols))

    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            if i - delta >= 0:
                delta_cepstrum[i, j] = cepstrum[i, j] - cepstrum[i - delta, j]
            if j - delta >= 0:
                **delta_cepstrum[i, j] = cepstrum[i, j] - cepstrum[i, j - delta]**  ---- Here is error in this line

    return delta_cepstrum

def compute_shifted_delta_cepstrum(cepstrum, window_size=3, delta=1):
    rows, cols = cepstrum.shape
    shifted_delta_cepstrum = np.zeros((rows, cols, window_size * 2 + 1))

    for shift in range(-window_size, window_size + 1):
        shifted_delta_cepstrum[:, :, shift + window_size] = compute_delta_cepstrum(cepstrum, delta + shift)

    return shifted_delta_cepstrum

# Load and preprocess the image
image_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/RMC2/Full Clean Run/sample.jpg'  # Replace with your image path
image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
image = image.astype(np.float32) / 255.0

# Compute cepstrum
cepstrum = compute_cepstrum(image)

# Compute shifted delta cepstrum
shifted_delta_cepstrum = compute_shifted_delta_cepstrum(cepstrum)

# Save or process the shifted delta cepstrum as needed
print("Shifted Delta Cepstrum calculation completed.")

I'm getting below error:
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-f742ff8a661b> in <cell line: 45>()
     43 
     44 # Compute shifted delta cepstrum
---> 45 shifted_delta_cepstrum = compute_shifted_delta_cepstrum(cepstrum)
     46 
     47 # Save or process the shifted delta cepstrum as needed

1 frames
<ipython-input-4-f742ff8a661b> in compute_delta_cepstrum(cepstrum, delta)
     21                 delta_cepstrum[i, j] = cepstrum[i, j] - cepstrum[i - delta, j]
     22             if j - delta >= 0:
---> 23                 delta_cepstrum[i, j] = cepstrum[i, j] - cepstrum[i, j - delta]
     24 
     25     return delta_cepstrum

IndexError: index 1740 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1740



Which version of Python are you using, and why did you tag this with another?

The problem here is almost certainly the range(-window_size,window_size+1).  At some point, you'll pass shift = window_size, which is beyond the edge of the image.

latest version of python Also For Tim ( It get pass the range line and called compute_delta_cepstrum function and error line is highlited

As @TimRoberts wrote, that's an out-of-bounds error – right in the first iteration in compute_shifted_delta_cepstrum(), where shift==-3, so delta in compute_delta_cepstrum() becomes -2. Once your inner for loop in compute_delta_cepstrum() reaches j==cols-2, you have j-delta==j-(-2)==cols and thus are beyond the bounds when trying to access cepstrum[i, j-delta]. Same problem with your outer loop (the one that increments i), but happens with j, as j is incremented first. To avoid this, also check the upper bounds: if j - delta >= 0 and j - delta < cols (same for i).

By the way, I don't understand the logic of your code, but are you sure it is doing the right thing? In the line delta_cepstrum[i, j] = cepstrum[i, j] - cepstrum[i - delta, j] you set delta_cepstrum[i, j], and two lines below, you immediately overwrite it with delta_cepstrum[i, j] = cepstrum[i, j] - cepstrum[i, j - delta] (unless the boundary check fails). Is it correct to overwrite the value this way, or shouldn't the two results maybe be combined somehow instead?

Look what happens when  shift is -window_size.  You'll pass delta+shift, which will be 1 + (-3) or -2.  So, inside compute_delta_cepstrum, delta will be -2.   Now you try to take cepstrum[i, j-delta] which is cepstrum[i, j+2]', which goes out of bounds.  You check for value to small, but not too large.
